# Exception Caught While Parsing WunderGround Weather Data

Tags: android, json

I am trying to Parse the JSON Data response from WunderGround API to get the temperature and other Few parameters, but every time I run into an exception.

Sample Data Response from WunderGround API.

```
{
"response": {
"version": "0.1",
"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
"features": {
"conditions": 1
}
},
"current_observation": {
"image": {
"url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
"title": "Weather Underground",
"link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
},
"display_location": {
"full": "San Francisco, CA",
"city": "San Francisco",
"state": "CA",
"state_name": "California",
"country": "US",
"country_iso3166": "US",
"zip": "94101",
"latitude": "37.77500916",
"longitude": "-122.41825867",
"elevation": "47.00000000"
},
"observation_location": {
"full": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
"city": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
"state": "California",
"country": "US",
"country_iso3166": "US",
"latitude": "37.773285",
"longitude": "-122.417725",
"elevation": "49 ft"
},
"estimated": {},
"station_id": "KCASANFR58",
"observation_time": "Last Updated on June 27, 5:27 PM PDT",
"observation_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:13 -0700",
"observation_epoch": "1340843233",
"local_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:14 -0700",
"local_epoch": "1340843234",
"local_tz_short": "PDT",
"local_tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles",
"local_tz_offset": "-0700",
"weather": "Partly Cloudy",
"temperature_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
"temp_f": 66.3,
"temp_c": 19.1,
"relative_humidity": "65%",
"wind_string": "From the NNW at 22.0 MPH Gusting to 28.0 MPH",
"wind_dir": "NNW",
"wind_degrees": 346,
"wind_mph": 22.0,
"wind_gust_mph": "28.0",
"wind_kph": 35.4,
"wind_gust_kph": "45.1",
"pressure_mb": "1013",
"pressure_in": "29.93",
"pressure_trend": "+",
"dewpoint_string": "54 F (12 C)",
"dewpoint_f": 54,
"dewpoint_c": 12,
"heat_index_string": "NA",
"heat_index_f": "NA",
"heat_index_c": "NA",
"windchill_string": "NA",
"windchill_f": "NA",
"windchill_c": "NA",
"feelslike_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
"feelslike_f": "66.3",
"feelslike_c": "19.1",
"visibility_mi": "10.0",
"visibility_km": "16.1",
"solarradiation": "",
"UV": "5",
"precip_1hr_string": "0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
"precip_1hr_in": "0.00",
"precip_1hr_metric": " 0",
"precip_today_string": "0.00 in (0 mm)",
"precip_today_in": "0.00",
"precip_today_metric": "0",
"icon": "partlycloudy",
"icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
"forecast_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html",
}
}
```

Click on the [Link](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api) For more details on WunderGround API.

I was successfully able to receive the above JSON response, but I think I am making some Mistake in parsing the data.

The function for Parsing the data is shown below:

```
public String getTemperature(String weatherData) {
    String temperature= null;
    try {
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(weatherData);
        JSONArray weatherforcastArray  = parentObject.getJSONArray("current_observation");
        JSONObject finalObject = weatherforcastArray.getJSONObject("temp_c"));
        return finalObject.getString("temp_c");



    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temperature;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the json response you posted, `temp_c` is a number, not string. So I declare it as double. Feel free to try this out:

```
public double getTemperature(String weatherData) {
    double temperature = Double.NaN;

    try {
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(weatherData);
        JSONObject currentObservation = parentObject.getJSONObject("current_observation");
        temperature = currentObservation.getDouble("temp_c");

        android.util.Log.i("TEST", "temp_c: " + temperature);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temperature;
}
```

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: Thanks...It Worked!.